# undefined method `home' for Dir:Class

Tags: shapado

I follow the shapado install with http://gitorious.org/shapado/shapado/blobs/master/README,
and when I execute rake bootstrap RAILS_ENV=development,it will generate some warnings and errors

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: The InstanceMethods module inside ActiveSupport::Concern will be no longer included automatically. Please define instance methods directly in Mongoid::Criteria instead. (called from include at /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/bundler/gems/mongoid_ext-edcb64748380/lib/mongoid_ext/criteria_ext.rb:15)
rake aborted!
undefined method `home' for Dir:Class
```

I am a newbie to ror,I am on the ubuntu-server 11.10 platform,so I don't know how resolve it

Answer (score 0):

I solved it:

1. to get rid of the DEPRECATION WARNING,just comment the code in criteria_ext.rb:15 as its instruction

   ## module InstanceMethods

   ## end
2. my ubuntu11.10 will first my install 1.8.7,when I execute ruby -v,it will show me that the current ruby version is 1.8.7,so it is sure that Dir.home method is not exist in 1.8.7,so I remove the default ruby in /usr/bin/ruby, then execute rvm --default use 1.9.3-p125
   it's not related with the shapado,it's only the ruby version of my mistaken